# Can't see or download OTA app from iPad in devices in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, core-data, ota

Our customer installs the iOS app via OTA on their iPads. Before, we would be able to download the apps from the iPads for debugging purposes and to extract the CoreData sqlite databases, from within the "Devices and Simulators" in Xcode.

However, this does not seem to be possible anymore since our app is not visible in the "Installed Apps" section. We are trying to this from the same mac where the app/ipa was originally build, so all certificates and provisioning profiles are there.

We are using Xcode 9.4.1 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and the iPads are iPad4 with iOS 11.4.1. I can't say for sure when this has stopped working, but I suspect it was after the last Xcode/iOS upgrade.

Is anyone experiencing the same problems?

Clarification: we have no trouble downloading the apps via OTA to the iPads and the apps are working as expected.

Comment: Is your device connected and trusted?

Comment: Yes. We are trying this with both our customers iPads and the iPads that we use for development.

Comment: If your app's IPA file size is less than 100MB you can try with Diawi link. and give that diawi link to client, he/she can install it from safari browser.

Comment: Please check this :https://dzone.com/articles/xcode-server-ios-over-the-air-ota-installation-tip